# PHP replace next occurence after "string" found

Tags: php, replace

I would like to know how to find and replace the next `;` after `command`

`command "bleh", 1234, 567;`

to

`command ("bleh", 1234, 567);`

This way is important, because string between command and ; can be completly different. 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions and [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$v = 'command "bleh", 1234, 567;';

$v = preg_replace('/command (.*?);/', 'command (\\1);', $v);
echo $v;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! Aaah, I still need to work on my pattern...

Comment: You are welcome :) When you do some simple pattern examples it will be much more easier for you in the future. I know, because few years ago I had similar problem :)